# Find all scripts with a given shebang line with find & sed

Tags: sed, grep, find, text, shebang

I want to find out all scripts with a specific shebang line. Specifically, I want all files that match the following criteria:

- It's mostly a plain text file (stuffs created by `gzexe` don't look very friendly)
- The 1st line contains solely `#!/bin/sh` or `#! /bin/sh` (with a space)

I would like to do this with `find`, `sed` and `grep` (`file` available).
File names are useless, because some scripts don't have extensions or even have wrong extensions. Also a `something.sh` may have a shebang line of `#!/bin/bash` which is also not what I wanted.

Besides, sometimes I would come across a file like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
blah.blah.blah...
```

The 1st line is empty and the shebang is located at the 2nd line, which **is not what I wanted**.
I am able to find shebang lines with `find|grep` but I don't know how to find lines **specifically on the 1st line** of a file.
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: So do you need to match the `#!` on the second line, or only the first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have GNU grep

```
grep -rIzl '^#![[:blank:]]*/bin/sh' ./
```

Answer (score 2):

I've combined multiple answers into my version:

```
find -type f -exec \
  sh -c 'head -n1 "$1" | grep -q "^#![[:blank:]]*/bin/sh"' _ {} \; \
  -print
```

- Taken from neuron it uses `find -type f -exec` to get all files and execute an command on it.
- Taken from user218374 it uses `head -n1` to get only the first line and use `grep -q` to get only the RC.
- Taken from Costas it uses `[[:blank:]]*` to handle spaces and tabs.
- Avoid the `echo` from neuron and instead use find's `-print` directive.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about which line the `#!/bin/sh` occurs in a file, then you can try:

`find -type f -exec bash -c 'grep -r "^#!.*\/bin\/sh" $1 1> /dev/null && echo $1' _ {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in ./*; do
   [ -f "$f" ] && [ -x "$f" ] &&
      file -b "$f" | grep -wq text &&
         head -n 1 "$f" | grep -qP '^#!\s*/bin/sh' &&
            printf '%s\n' "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If various types of executables regardless permissions (i.e. `+x`) or shebang:

```bash
find . \
    -type f `# Files only` \
    -exec bash -c \
        $'file -b -- \'{}\' | grep -qP -- \'executable$\'' \; `# Executable` \
    -print; # Print the path if "exec" exits with status 0
```

If those with shebang only regardless permissions (i.e. `+x`):

```bash
find . \
    -type f `# Files only` \
    -exec bash -c \
        $'head -n 1 -- \'{}\' | grep -qP -- \'^#!.+\'' \; `# With shebang` \
    -print; # Print the path if "exec" exits with status 0
```

If those with current User executable permission only:

```bash
find . \
    -type f `# Files only` \
    -exec $'test -x \'{}\'' `# With current User executable permission` \
    -print; # Print the path if "exec" exits with status 0
```